# Noob question on scale

Tags: modeling, scale

I'm very new to Blender and am specifically focused on 3D printing. I've made several objects and checked all the geometry to make sure everything is Kosher. No flipped normals, no intersecting faces, yadda, yadda. I run the 3D Print checks and everything checks out.

The problem is that when I try to scale an object to size for printing, all hell breaks loose and 3D print check starts showing the entire object as zero faces, intersect faces everywhere, etc.

Here is the work flow.

1. I check 3D print to confirm everything is good.
2. In Object mode I scale the object down and apply scale.
3. Check 3d print again. Intersecting faces everywhere and zero faces.
4. I undo everything and go back to the start.
5. I try scaling in Edit mode and check 3D print.
6. Same damn thing.

This happens with every object, but I made a very simple hammer model as a test bed. This way I know there won't be any hidden geometry or errors that I'm missing. But even with this very simple and rudimentary model the same thing keeps happening.

I have scanned every tutorial and discussion I can find and there is nothing out there that addresses this. Can someone please explain this.

I've been trying to solve this for days and am at a dead end. Can anyone explain this, please?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is your object made of multiple parts? It could be that when you 'scale' them it's resulting in intersecting geometry as the parts are scaling from their own origin points. You might need to 'join' them into one mesh or change the pivot point to all work from the same origin. Please update your question with more information and perhaps some screenshots of your current model.

Comment: Have you pressed CRTL A -> Scale before exporting?

Comment: Iam not really sure, I print and scale regularly but never came across this issue. Do you have any modificators applied?

Comment: It's a single object. No modifiers. Like I said, I broke this down into as simple an object as possible to see if it still happens and it does. If I can't make an object this simple work, then what chance do I have with anything that's actually complicated.

Comment: Added two pics showing before scale and after. And YES, I applied the scale by hitting Ctrl A.

Comment: I have no idea what this means. "Are you scaling below floating-point resolution? Like, 0.000000000003 Km, instead of 0.000003 mm? –"

Comment: Unit scale is set to 1.000 . Length is Milimeters.

Comment: This seems like a glitch.  You could try reporting it.  Ultimately, those results are just a guide.  If you know your geometry is solid, don't worry about it, go ahead and export it for printing.  I've only had things 3D printed through services; I don't have my own 3D printer, so my hands-on experience with slicing software is limited, but I'm pretty sure most of them have options to explicitly tell what scale to print the model at, so I wouldn't worry about scaling in Blender.  Its measurements never seemed to be consistent with what the slicing program read them as anyway.